# Having issues with <fig> in code

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

def graphRawFX():
    date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack = True,
                              delimiter=',',
                              converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('Y%m%d%H%M%S')}
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    ax1=plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

    ax1.plot(date, bid)
    ax1.plot(date, ask)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show
```

the line: fig=plt.figure gives me a syntax error? Has anyone an idea what could be the problem. 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `)` at the end of this line:

```
converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('Y%m%d%H%M%S')}
```

Append `)`at the end:

```
converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('Y%m%d%H%M%S')})
```